# JAVA Netbeans - How to print currently playing song

Tags: java

I have this Audioplayer in Java.
I want to be able to print out info about the currently playing song, but I can't seem to get it to work.
How do I go about this?
Please let me know if you need more info.

```
package BLL;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoundControlMenu extends Menu {

AudioPlayer p;
final String fileA = "hi";

/**
 *
 */
public SoundControlMenu() {
    super("      Sound Controls",
            "|Play              |",
            "|Pause             |",
            "|Resume            |",
            "|Stop              |",
            "|Now playing       |");
      }

 /**
 * @param option
 * @void prints the SoundControlMenu
 */
@Override
protected void doAction(int option)  {
    switch (option) {
        case 0:
            if (p != null) {
                p.stop();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            App.Menu.getInstance().showSongs();
            System.out.println("Enter song title:");
            String chooseSong = scanner.nextLine();
            chooseSong = chooseSong.replace(" ", "");
            if (p != null) {
                p.stop();
            }
            p = new AudioPlayer(chooseSong + ".mp3");

            if (p.isValid() == false) {
                System.out.println("The audio player is not working -- " + p.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                p.startToPlay();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (p != null) {
                p.pause();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (p != null) {
                p.resume();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (p != null) {
                p.stop();
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (p == null) {
                System.out.println("No audio player exist...");
            } else if (p.isPlaying()) {
                System.out.println(fileA);
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOT playing...");
            }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: 1.) replace all `chooseSong` with `fileA` or 2.) put below `chooseSong = chooseSong.replace(" ", "");` following `fileA = chooseSong;` 3.) to get song title with spaces put it above `chooseSong.replace`

Comment: Thank you very much @moskito-x! I tried 1) first but it did not work. I got the error message `variable fileA may not have been initialized`, so I went on to 2) which worked perfectly. Again, thank you!
Still new to this site - how can I make your comment the "Answer"?

Comment: answer your own question. Write what you have done to get it to work. One day later `accept` your answer.

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE. It has nothing to do with this question whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP, So the code is 100% same on different platforms? The differences are in the tools?

Answer (score 0):

Following @moskito-x's advice,

I inserted `fileA = chooseSong;`

```
[...]
chooseSong = chooseSong.replace(" ", "");
fileA = chooseSong; 
[...]
```

which worked.